# Python Tkinter with SQL Points Management System

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, tkinter

Show Credits secured based on response received on a form. The user belongs to a certain department and, on responding yes or no, gets some points added to his record.

Logic Table:

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDLPo.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDLPo.png)

BackEnd Table:
[image: BackEnd Table]

Input Form[image: Input Form]

I am looking for 2 parts:

1. Default User Name and Department from the login
2. Get the points calculated in real time and stored in the back end table

I am new to Python and would like some help with the pseudo code. I am using Python tkinter and SQL server in the back end

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Please [edit] to convert your images of text into actual text. [See here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/20170164) for why. See also: ["how to format a table in a post"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277716/20170164).

Comment: The python sql connections are working fine. Since this is a home project, I was able to create a rudimentary a login , registration page and used tree view to store some data. But this part kind of gets me a thought block